# Prevent Chrome from setting font-size on HTML paste into contenteditable

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, contenteditable

To reproduce:

1. Run the MVCE snippet on both Firefox desktop and Chrome desktop.
2. Open FF desktop, then copy "foobar" from source.
3. Open Chrome desktop, and paste into target (after the colon in `here:`)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const info = document.querySelector('.info'),
    pinfo = document.querySelector('.paste-info'),
    target = document.querySelector('.target');
  setInterval(() => {
    const sel = ".source *, .target *"
    info.innerHTML = '';
    for (const elm of [...document.querySelectorAll(sel)]) {
      info.innerHTML += "TAG: " + elm.tagName + "; TEXT: " + elm.innerText +  "; FONTSIZE: " + window.getComputedStyle(elm)['font-size'] + "<br>";
    }
  }, 1000);
  target.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
    pinfo.innerHTML += "PASTE HTML: <pre>" + e.clipboardData.getData('text/html').replaceAll('<', '&lt;').replaceAll('>', '&gt;') + '</pre><br>';
  });
};
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="source" contenteditable=true>Source text: <b>foobar</b></div>

<div style="font-size: 14px">
  <div contenteditable=true class="target">Destination, <h1>paste here:</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="info"></div>
<div class="paste-info"></div>
```

You will notice that:

1. Clipboard data contains `<b>foobar</b>` (see content after `PASTE HTML:`), but...
2. The actually pasted HTML has `style="font-size: 14px;"` set on the `b` element (The 14px size comes from the parent of the contenteditable).

I expect the pasted HTML to not have any font sizes set on it, because they were not specified in the source clipboard data.

> **Question:** How to force Chrome to not put any font sizes on the pasted HTML, when there is no font-size present on the source HTML?

I tried one workaround: to set `font-size: unset/revert` on the source, but it causes `font-size: unset` to also be present in the pasted HTML. I prefer to not have any font-size to be present in the pasted HTML.

---

The context of this code is a Chrome extension, and I control the text/html data that is pasted into the target. I can attach a paste event listeners on the target contenteditable, but I cannot alter the HTML/styles of contents *after* it has been pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the "normal" pasting of the HTML markup by using the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).
The steps are

- In the paste event handler, get the `Range` object representing the current selection.
- Use this `Range` object to parse the pasted HTML markup into a `DocumentFragment` object thanks to the [`createContextualFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) method.
- Remove the previously selected content ([`Range#deleteContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/deleteContents)).
- [Insert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/insertNode) the `DocumentFragment` object we created at step 2, where the cursor is.
- [Collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/collapse) the current `Range` object so that the cursor goes to the end of the newly pasted content.

Doing all these steps manually will prevent the browser's "smart" handling of the rich-text content; only what's in the clipboard will be parsed.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const info = document.querySelector('.info'),
    pinfo = document.querySelector('.paste-info'),
    target = document.querySelector('.target');
  setInterval(() => {
    const sel = ".source *, .target *"
    info.innerHTML = '';
    for (const elm of [...document.querySelectorAll(sel)]) {
      info.innerHTML += "TAG: " + elm.tagName + "; TEXT: " + elm.innerText +  "; FONTSIZE: " + window.getComputedStyle(elm)['font-size'] + "<br>";
    }
  }, 1000);
  target.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
    pinfo.innerHTML += "PASTE HTML: <pre>" + e.clipboardData.getData('text/html').replaceAll('<', '&lt;').replaceAll('>', '&gt;') + '</pre><br>';

    e.preventDefault();
    const markup = e.clipboardData.getData("text/html") ||
      e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
    const sel = getSelection();
    const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    const frag = range.createContextualFragment(markup);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(frag);
    range.collapse();
  });
};
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="source" contenteditable=true>Source text: <b>foobar</b></div>

<div style="font-size: 14px">
  <div contenteditable=true class="target">Destination, <h1>paste here:</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="info"></div>
<div class="paste-info"></div>
```

One big drawback to this method though: **This will not make an entry in the edit history.** This means that after your users did paste any content there, they'll be unable to undo that action.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is comprehensive and the most usable so far. I'm still sad we can't use the regular paste event. I was hoping for a `event.preventSpecialPaste = true` flag that would prevent the browser's interference. I'll wait for any other answers and award bounty to you tomorrow.

Comment: Truth is I was hoping for `document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, markup)` to work (It would also have enabled the edit-history thing), but it seems they interfere in that one too...

Comment: I think there is one more problem with this approach apart from the paste issue. Most modern editors like TinyMCE/CKeditor maintain an internal state of the visible content. This internal state is updated based user events like paste (triggered by user or via execCommand). I do _not_ think that `range.insertNode` will generate any such event. So, there is a risk of the internal editor state becoming inconsistent with the visible content. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its possible to intercept the pasting event, and alter the contents of the paste to force it to paste as plain text using js.

I've added an id of `id="editor"` on the `contenteditable` div.  and added the following js code:

```
const editorEle = document.getElementById('editor');

// Handle the paste event
editorEle.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
    // Prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the copied text from the clipboard
    const text = e.clipboardData
        ? (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
        : // For IE
        window.clipboardData
        ? window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
        : '';

    if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    } else {
        // Insert text at the current position of caret
        const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        range.insertNode(textNode);
        range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
        range.collapse(false);

        const selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
});
```

here's a snippet of it running. let me know if this solved your issue:

```js
const editorEle = document.getElementById('editor');

// Handle the `paste` event
editorEle.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
    // Prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the copied text from the clipboard
    const text = e.clipboardData
        ? (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
        : // For IE
        window.clipboardData
        ? window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
        : '';

    if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    } else {
        // Insert text at the current position of caret
        const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        range.insertNode(textNode);
        range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
        range.collapse(false);

        const selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
});




window.onload = function() {
  const info = document.querySelector('.info'),
    pinfo = document.querySelector('.paste-info'),
    target = document.querySelector('.target');
  setInterval(() => {
    const sel = ".source *, .target *"
    info.innerHTML = '';
    for (const elm of [...document.querySelectorAll(sel)]) {
      info.innerHTML += "TAG: " + elm.tagName + "; TEXT: " + elm.innerText +  "; FONTSIZE: " + window.getComputedStyle(elm)['font-size'] + "<br>";
    }
  }, 1000);
  target.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
    pinfo.innerHTML += "PASTE HTML: <pre>" + e.clipboardData.getData('text/html').replaceAll('<', '&lt;').replaceAll('>', '&gt;') + '</pre><br>';
  });
};
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="source" contenteditable=true>Source text: <b>foobar</b></div>

<div style="font-size: 14px">
  <div contenteditable=true id="editor" class="target">Destination, <h1>paste here:</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="info"></div>
<div class="paste-info"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. You suggest "alter the contents of the paste to force it to paste as plain text using js." However, in the code, you have prevented default on the paste event, and then proceeded to insert text manually (using execCommand/Range APIs). So the code does not match your suggestion.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I apologize for my semantics. Does this code work for you though?

Comment: It does not, unfortunately. Preventing default on events like 'paste' on internet websites can break them in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 0):

(here as anwer because more space than comment, will remove when issue resolved/closed)

Given the system wide behavior of iOS and Windows when copy/pasting text, Chrome seems to provide the generally expected result.

Expected when selecting some text/element and [Ctrl-C] copy:

- [Ctrl-V] paste with markup
- [Ctrl-Shift-V] paste without markup

This is exactly what Chrome does, making Firefox the odd one out.

The above obviously doesn't not resolve your issue, but following the above you should be preventing FF from stripping the markup. This will add to your issue, because what did FF do with the original markup??

**UPDATE**

I think I figured it out: 'foobar' has no font settings, therefore it `inherit` it's size from nearest parent => `14px`. This info is inside the copied 'package' (`clipboardData`). Firefox strips it by default on [Ctrl-V], where Chrome does not.

As `h1` stretches to `100%` (filling destination) in FF 'foobar' is `2em` while in Chrome it is `14px` on [Ctrl-V]. [Ctrl-V] basically should not strip, where [Ctrl-Shift-V] should. Hense my comment that Chrome does it correctly as the `font-size` after [Ctrl-Shift-V] is indeed `2em` because of the `h1` stretch.

While redundant in FF, you could strip all info from the `clipboardData` inside the paste event, or rely on the [Ctrl-V]/[Ctrl-Shift-V] mechanism.

**UPDATE 2**

There is more going on. I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/poKNjWw) for testing.

Pasting in succession right after 'paste here:' *and* 'Destination, '
with both [Ctrl-V] and [Ctrl-Shift-V] randomly shows that info gets stripped when [Ctrl-Shift-V] is used first a few times. After using [Ctrl-V] and then [Ctrl-Shift-V] again, the stripping take no longer place (the text stays bold in either case).

Leads me to think that next to the different [Ctrl-V]/[Ctrl-Shift-V] handling of both browsers, the internal text editor has a few flaws I cannot get my head around...

Comment: Hi Rene, you seem to talk about a different thing. In my question, there is no CSS style information in the markup in the source clipboard data. But there is CSS style information in markup after paste. This inconsistency is what my question is about. Please re-check.